# SQL Triple Join: unable to triple join

Tags: sql-server, join

I am an Analyst with some experience in SQL but i have yet to join more than 2 tables. I'm trying to join these 3 tables and I am not able to bind the tables together with success. What am I doing wrong?

```
Use Db3
Select Persons.DateOfBirth
, Persons.DisabilityCode
, Persons.Ethnicity
, Persons.Gender
, Persons.Country
, Persons.MaritalStatus
, Persons.Suffix
, Persons.LastName
, Persons.FirstName
, Persons.MiddleName
, Persons.CommonOrPreferredName
, Persons.Credentials
, Persons.IsActive
, Persons.MilitaryStatus
, Jobs.Id
, Jobs.AdjustedDateOfHire
, Jobs.DateOfHire
, Jobs.CompanyOwnershipStatus
, Jobs.LeaveDate
, Jobs.TerminationDate
, OrganizationalAssociations.Id
, OrganizationalAssociations.EmployeeNumber
, OrganizationalAssociations.SourceSystemEmployeeId
, OrganizationalAssociations.EmploymentType 
From Persons Person

JOIN Persons ON Persons.Id = Jobs.Id
JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.Id = Persons.Id
JOIN OrganizationalAssociations ON OrganizationalAssociations.Id = Persons.Id
```

Error Message: Jobs.Id could not be bound

Comment: Can you post table structure of the three tables?  Is there an Id column on the Jobs table in the database Db3?

Comment: you are joining four tables using Persons table twice

Comment: Do you really need the first JOIN (Persons to self) in this query?

Comment: why are you joining Persons to Persons?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the join with `Person` table `JOIN Persons ON Persons.Id = Jobs.Id`. Your query should look like below after removing the join with Person table

```
Use Db3
Select Persons.DateOfBirth
, p.DisabilityCode
, p.Ethnicity
, p.Gender
, p.Country
, p.MaritalStatus
, p.Suffix
, p.LastName
, p.FirstName
, p.MiddleName
, p.CommonOrPreferredName
, p.Credentials
, p.IsActive
, p.MilitaryStatus
, j.Id
, j.AdjustedDateOfHire
, j.DateOfHire
, j.CompanyOwnershipStatus
, j.LeaveDate
, j.TerminationDate
, o.Id
, o.EmployeeNumber
, o.SourceSystemEmployeeId
, o.EmploymentType 
From Persons p
JOIN Jobs j ON j.Id = p.Id
JOIN OrganizationalAssociations o ON o.Id = p.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need the first join..
Remove the line JOIN Persons ON Persons.Id = Jobs.Id and try. You should be good.